# "process is not defined" when used in a function (Vue/Quasar)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

The following snippet represents a Pinia store in  my Vue 3 / Quasar 2 application. This store uses the environment variable `VUE_APP_BACKEND_API_URL` which shall be read from either the `window` object or `process.env`.

However I don't understand why the first variant is wokring but the second is not. Using the `getEnv` function always results in a `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined` error.

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

function getEnv(name) {
  return window?.appConfig?.[name] || process.env[name];
}

// 1. this is working
const backendApiUrl = window?.appConfig?.VUE_APP_BACKEND_API_URL || process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_API_URL;

// 2. this is NOT working
const backendApiUrl = getEnv('VUE_APP_BACKEND_API_URL');

export const useAppConfigStore = defineStore('appConfig', {
  state: () => ({
    authorizationUrl: new URL(
      '/oauth2/authorization/keycloak',
      backendApiUrl,
    ).toString(),
    logoutUrl: new URL('/logout', backendApiUrl).toString(),
    backendApiUrl: new URL(backendApiUrl).toString(),
  }),
});
```

Comment: The error means that `window?.appConfig?.[name]` was falsy, which would mean that it can't find either `window`, `window.appConfig` or `window.appConfig.VUE_APP_BACKEND_API_URL`. To me it looks like nr 1 and nr 2 should do the same thing, unless you are running into context problems (e.g. when you would do `window?.localStorage?.[functionName]` with `getItem` you end up having to bind the right context for it to work). I doesn't seem like that would be relevant here though. Can you step through that function with a debugger to check what it believes `window` and `window.appConfig` to be?

Comment: The fact that `window.appConfig.VUE_APP_BACKEND_API_URL` (or any part of it) may be falsy is correct. That's why the value defined by `process.env` should be used as a fallback. The main problem is that actually the `process` object is not (yet) defined.

Comment: `process` is only defined in node. Are you sure the error is thrown in the server-side script, and not in code that is running in the browser?

Comment: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-process-env#caveats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NodeJS-specific stuff like `process` doesn't exist in the browser environments. Both Webpack and Vite implementations work by **replacing** `process.env.XYZ` expressions with their values on **build time**. So, just `process.env`, or `process.env[name]` will not be replaced, which will lead to the errors you are experiencing. See the [caveats](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/handling-process-env#caveats) section and related Webpack/Vite docs and resources. So, unfortunately, the only easy way seems to be the first long and repetitive way you've tried(`const backendApiUrl = window?.appConfig?.VUE_APP_BACKEND_API_URL || process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_API_URL;`). You can try embedding this logic in a single object, then use the function to access it.

```js
const config = {
  VUE_APP_BACKEND_API_URL: window?.appConfig?.VUE_APP_BACKEND_API_URL || process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_API_URL
}

export function getEnv(name) {
  return config[name];
}
```

This way it will be longer and more repetitive to define it the first time, but at least you will be able to use it easily through the code base.

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but it might help someone, I was able to resolve this by adding below to my quasar.conf.js

```
    build: {
      vueRouterMode: 'hash', // available values: 'hash', 'history'
      env: {
        API_ENDPOINT: process.env.API_ENDPOINT ? process.env.API_ENDPOINT : 'http://stg.....com',
        API_ENDPOINT_PORT: process.env.API_ENDPOINT_PORT ? process.env.API_ENDPOINT_PORT : '0000',
        ...env
      },
    }
```

For more information ge here: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/discussions/9967